# mysql query doesn't run although db connection is successful and query is right

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Successful DB connection is established and in all other pages in my website the counts and description of different items are successfully queried from tables and being displayed.

But, similar SQLquery somehow not working while login

The below is my code:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');  // Connection is successful
session_start();
if($_POST)
{
    $email_id = $_POST['email_id']; // i can echo "$email_id" in console

    $password = $_POST['password'];  // i can echo "$password" in console 

    $sql1 = "select * from user where user_email='$email_id' and user_password='$password' ";
    $strSQL_Result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($strSQL_Result);

    if($count==1){
...//do some stuff
```

It is expected that the **$count** value could be either 0 or 1, but nothing is being returned because the query itself is not going through.

The same query when run directly in database produces result so the attributes are all correct.

In console I can see successful XHR POST with the email ID and password entered in login form. 
Thereafter this login.php file being called to authenticate user from DB where it is unable to do

Comment: Turn on error reporting and find out what error you are getting.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: @Epodax where to turn error reporting exactly, did you mean console or ..could you please be specific

Comment: use mysqli_error() to read the error running SQL query. Also, secure your query.

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries.  Munging query strings can lead to unexpected syntax errors -- as well as SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @tereško sql injections part will be handled once after it starts working, or could you please be specific

Comment: check for errors then, via php and the query. I can't see this failing otherwise.

Comment: In the console, in the script, where ever you want, google "Turn on php error reporting"

Comment: `if($count==1)` you're also checking if there is only the "one" record. If you have duplicate entries, then that will fail. Check your POST arrays if they have value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am making sure to enter such an "email" and "password" which exists only once in my table so, when the exact same query run in db it returns 1 results

Comment: `var_dump($variable_or_POST_array);` your POST arrays/variables, make  sure no whitespace was introduced in them or the data in the db table. You say you connected successfully, using mysqli_ right? as I said earlier; I can't see this failing, unless you didn't name your inputs, or the form doesn't use a POST method, this could be anything. There really isn't enough to go on with what you posted.

Comment: its uses form to get login inputs, that's how the flow is coming till this file which is named as say login.php   I have also mentioned that i can echo email id and password and can see them getting logged in console.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this could be trivial but it finally produced result after hours of figuring out

the file `connection.php` lies in same folder as my website root folder so I was using `include('connection.php');`

but when I used `include('../connection.php');` it worked.

this is because the called file `login.php` which is shown in the question and the `connection.php` file which gives `$con` variable are not in same directory. so we have to use `../` into the path